# Updating modules on VPS hosted under OpenVZ

Tags: linux, vps, openvz

Been trying to install OpenVPN on a VPS but come into a few problems when trying to start the openvpn server:

```
Service deferred error: IPTablesServiceBase: failed to run iptables-restore [status=1]: ['FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/2.6.18-028stab070.14/modules.dep: No such file or directory', 'FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/2.6.18-028stab070.14/modules.dep: No such file or directory', 'iptables-restore: line 46 failed']: internet/base:1175,internet/base:752,internet/process:45,internet/process:306,internet/_baseprocess:48,internet/process:775,internet/_baseprocess:60,svc/pp:116,svc/svcnotify:26,internet/defer:238,internet/defer:307,internet/defer:323,sagent/ipts:105,sagent/ipts:39,util/error:52,util/error:32
service failed to start due to unresolved dependencies: set(['user', 'iptables_openvpn'])
service failed to start due to unresolved dependencies: set(['user', 'iptables_openvpn'])
service failed to start due to unresolved dependencies: set(['iptables_openvpn'])
```

Anyway so after a bit of playing around and some advice, I found that the Linux kernel and modules don't match on my server.

`uname -r` returns `2.6.18-028stab070.14` and `ls /lib/modules` returns `2.6.18-028stab070.7`

The server is running OpenVZ and my container uses Ubuntu 9.10.

So my question is, is it possible for me to update my modules on a VPS and if so how would I do this, or is this something I'll need to try get my host to do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kernel modules are the host's responsibility on OpenVZ.